# My texture is pure white but it is greyish in viewport

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

My texture is pure white but it is greyish in viewport. Is there a way to make it pure white without changing the rest of the texture's color? I imagine it has to do with the texture being affected by light? I already put a shader to have the transparent part of my PNG texture actually be transparent in Blender. I really dont know how to use the shaders in Blender so I get tangled up easily.

[image]

Comment: I think it's about lighthing. Can you try adding a light source next to your object?